# Skip suggestion string value from Android EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an Android EditText with suggestions enabled. My goal is not to disable suggestion (since i'm able to do that), but to skip some string values from them.

For example, suppose that i'd like to skip 'hello' word.
If i write 'he' in the EditText, my suggestions list shouldn't contain 'hello' since it's a string that has to be skipped. Is it possible?

Hope i explained myself, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure, but seems like the only way is to implement your own `AutoCompleteTextView`, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

Comment: Ok, could be a solution, but i have to implement adapter and fill it with my own data strings. This way make me skip some values, but i'm going to loose android suggestion logic for all other words, since strings shown are taken only from my data adapter